# Help with understanding use of Big Bracket in this Context

Tags: bash, shell-script, wildcards

```
[ ! -d ~/.ssh ] && mkdir ~/.ssh;
```

I cannot understand the use of `[]` here and what does this mean. Although I understand the later part I cannot relate  `[ ! -d ~/.ssh ]` with `mkdir ~/.ssh`

Thankyou!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That has nothing to do with globbing, it is a standard shell `if` condition. The `[` is a shell builtin (also an external command) that is used for tests. What you have written is equivalent to this:

```bsh
if [ ! -d ~/.ssh ]; 
then 
    mkdir ~/.ssh
fi
```

As explained in `help [` (in bash):

```
$ help [
[: [ arg... ]
    Evaluate conditional expression.
    
    This is a synonym for the "test" builtin, but the last argument must
    be a literal `]', to match the opening `['.
```

Here, we are using the test `-d` to check if `~/.ssh` is a directory. You can see the various test options with `help test` (again in bash). Here, we are using these two:

```
$ help test | grep -E -- '^ *!|-d'
      -d FILE        True if file is a directory.
      ! EXPR         True if expr is false.
```

This means that `[ ! -d ~/.ssh ]` will be true if `~/.ssh` is not a directory.

Now that we know that `[` is a command that the shell can run, it can be treated like other commands. The syntax `command && otherCommand` is also standard and means "run `otherCommand` only if `command` was successful". So here, you are saying "create the directory `~/.ssh` if it does not already exist:

```
[ ! -d ~/.ssh ] && mkdir ~/.ssh;
--------------- -- ------------
       |        |        |=======> "otherCommand"
       |        |================> logical AND
       |=========================> "if ~/.ssh is not a directory" (command)
```